# HTML <select> focus issue: 2 clicks needed with Firefox to select an <option>

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, focus, html-select

I'm working on a custom SELECT component with roughly the following structure (psuedoish example).

```
<span>
  <select onclick=chooseAnOptionAndCloseSelect>
    <option>
      .
      .
    <option>
  </select>
  <input onclick=displaySelectAndOptions onchange=filterOptionsAccordingTheInput />
</span>
```

So clicking the INPUT opens the custom SELECT component that has OPTIONs inside.
I'm filtering the displayed options with jQuery according to the input field's value.

The focus is naturally on the input while typing values. After filtering some options I want to click on one of them. **Problem is, that two clicks are required with Firefox, first apparently focuses the select element again** (focus was on input) **and only second click gives the desired outcome** triggering of the the onclick event on the select (which passes on the option index).

On IE this works fine, single click is enough for selection after filtering values.

I cannot use focus re-direction because I do not want to disturb the user. That is to say the focus needs to stay on the input as long as the user likes so he/she can filter the values to their heart's content.

Could some clever use of JS/jQuery listeners or having single click behave as double click do the trick? Any ideas appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I'm having some progress with the following approach (mouseup nested within onfocus):

```
$(function() { // <- document.ready
    $('select[data-filtered=true]').on('focus', function(evt) { // <- onfocus
        $(this).mouseup(function(evt) { // <- Find out that it  was a mouse click
            // This is the problematic part.
            // I need to find out somehow which <option> to mark as selected
            $(this).children().get(X).selected = true; // <- children are the <options>
            $(this).click(); // <- trigger a normal onclick handler 
        });
    });
});
```

So the `<option>` that the mouse is over during the onfocus event should be marked as selected = true. Any suggestions? Extracting the mouse cordinates followed by more nested events perhaps?

Comment: your markup looks invalid as need double quotes for `<select onclick=chooseAnOptionAndCloseSelect>`. Can you please share jsfiddle also.

Comment: Yeah it seems like a fiddle would definitely speed things up here

Comment: Reminder: event calls are pseudo, thats why I didn't include double quotes.  

I'll try to see if I can whip up a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I was rather close after the last update :P, solved with code below.

```
$(function() {
    $('select[data-filtered=true]').on('focus', function(evt) {
        $(this).mouseup(function(evt) { 
            evt.target.selected = true;
            $(this).click();
        });
    });
});
```

This effectively performs the second mouse click that would otherwise be required from the user in my case.

Adding the inline version as well (that I need to use due JSF):

```
onfocus="$(this).mouseup(function(evt) {evt.target.selected = true;$(this).click();});"
```